# Find $2$ unit vectors orthogonal to $(2,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that in order to find an orthogonal vector to $(2,1)$ I will solve this :

$\langle(x,y),(2,1)\rangle = 0 $

but I don't understand how this is related to $2$ unit vectors.

Comment: Once you find an (non-zero) orthogonal vector, any multiple of it will also be orthogonal. Choose multiples that give vectors of length one.

Comment: In other words, you have to normalize the vectors

Comment: Also, if $u$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $(2,1)$, so is $-u$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did:

$$2x+y=1\iff y=1-2x\,,\,\,\text{so for example}\;\;u:=\binom{\;\;1}{-1}
$$

is one possibility and, in fact, all the solutions are given by (assuming we're in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$)

$$S:=\left\{\;\binom {\;\;x}{\!\!-2x}\;;\;\;x\in\Bbb R\right\}+u=\text{Span}\,\left\{\;\binom{\;\;1}{-2}\;\right\}+\binom{\;\;1}{-1}$$

Note that

$$||u||=\sqrt{1+1}=\sqrt2\implies \frac u{\sqrt2}\;\;\text{is a unit vector, and thus}$$

$$\frac {ku}{\sqrt2}=\binom{\;\frac k{\sqrt2}}{\!\!-\frac k{\sqrt2}}$$

is a vector of length $\;k\;$ and orthogonal to what you want